# Uploading a File to Google Drive : Insufficient Permission

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I am trying to upload the image file green.png to my google drive but continue to get the error the message

> "INSUFFICIENT PERMISSION".

I suspect it has to do with my `SCOPES`. I have modified my scopes many times and continue to get the error.

Does anyone have any ideas what I could do to my code to successfully upload it to my drive? Thank you

```
var path = require("path");
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const OAuth2Client = google.auth.OAuth2;
const TOKEN_PATH = 'credentials.json';
var fileArr=[];
var multipart = require('connect-multiparty');
var multipartMiddleware = multipart();
var multer = require("multer");
var upload = multer({dest: "./uploads"});
const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.photos.readonly',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata',
            ];   

module.exports=function(app){
 app.post("/upload2", upload.array('file', 4) , function(req, res, next){
    const TOKEN_PATH = 'credentials.json';
      fs.readFile('client_secret.json', (err, content) => {
         if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:',          
         err);
        authorize(JSON.parse(content), UploadFiles);
         });

         function authorize(credentials, callback) {
           const {client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris} = 
            credentials.installed;
           const oAuth2Client = new OAuth2Client(client_id, client_secret, 
           redirect_uris[0]);
           fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
           if (err) return getAccessToken(oAuth2Client, callback);
           oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
           callback(oAuth2Client);
            });
           }

        function UploadFiles(auth) {
         console.log(auth)
         const drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth});
         var folderId = '1AM07eNAJz5D4oFa5ZB-0ygOa_tVjoAgR';
          var fileMetadata = {
              'name': 'green.png'
               parents: [folderId]
           };
          var media = {
              mimeType: 'image/png',
              body: fs.createReadStream('./img/green.png')
           };

         drive.files.create({
           resource: fileMetadata,
           media: media,
           fields: 'id'
        }, function (err, file) {
           if (err) {
          // Handle error
          console.log(err);
           } else {
             console.log('File Id: ', file.id);
            }
        });

       }
    })
  }
```

Comment: code: 403,  errors:
   [ { domain: 'global', reason: 'insufficientPermissions',
       message: 'Insufficient Permission' } ] }

Answer (score 0):

> code: 403, errors: [ { domain: 'global', reason: 'insufficientPermissions', message: 'Insufficient Permission' } ] }

Means exactly that the user you have authenticated with does not have permissions to do what you are trying to do.

In your case one of two things is probably the cause of your issue.

Either the user you have authenticated with does not have access to the folder below you may have miss typed it it may belong to another user and you have forgotten to share with with this user.

```
var folderId = '1AM07eNAJz5D4oFa5ZB-0ygOa_tVjoAgR';
```

Second option is that you are currently including every scope under the sun you really dont need to.  But if when you first authenticated this user you only had for example read me requested then the user has only granted permission to read me.   You need to authenticate your user and it will prompt for permissions for the additional scopes you have added in your code and it will then work.

You really only need this it gives access to everything.

```
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
```

Comment: I am able to list all my files from the filder to my site. When a user comes to the site the page populates with images from my drive folder so I get instant gratification that its working. The user can upload their image but as I am testing I am clearly having issues with the permissions of CREATING a file but not listing the files. Lastly, I switched the scope to only the one suggested and still throws the error. Also the folder Ids match.

Comment: If you are accessing data on your persona drive folder and not a users drive folder you should be using a service account not Oauth2.   Just remember to grant the service account access to the folder in question. it will be able to upload the files to the folder.

Comment: I am sorry I cannot visualize what you are trying to say. Do you have any sample code that explains what you are saying.